Allure/Junit5 test result doesn't contain data-driven tests' parameters
I'm writing REST API tests, using REST-assured library and Allure's Junit5 adapter. When running parametrized tests, I'm expecting test parameters to be displayed in report like so:
parameters correctly displayed
but am getting this:
parametrs not added
I'm not talking about tests' names, but the lack of "Parameters" section.
Code of my test is:
@Epic("some epic")
@Feature("some feature")
@Story("some story")
class SomeTests {
    @ParameterizedTest()
    @CsvSource(textBlock = """
           KEY,VAL
           foo,bar
           lubie,placki
           """, useHeadersInDisplayName = true)
    void parametrizedTest(String key, String val) {
        Allure.step("Some step");
        assertThat(key).isNotEqualTo(val);
    }
}

and pom.xml is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- dependencies versions -->
        <junit.version>5.10.2</junit.version>
        <allure.version>2.27.0</allure.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.22.1</aspectj.version>
        <assertj.version>3.25.3</assertj.version>
        <rest-assured.version>5.4.0</rest-assured.version>
        <jackson-databind.version>2.17.1</jackson-databind.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.32</lombok.version>
        <!-- plugins versions -->
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.2.5</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${allure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- allure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-java-commons</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit-platform</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-databind.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <!-- AspectJ is needed to process some annotation like @Attachment etc.-->
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>2.23.0</reportVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

For debugging purposes, I created listener extending TestLifecycleListener and at stage of "beforeTestWrite", TestResult object's "parameters" field doesn't contain test's parameters.
What do I do wrong?
